# How is "Distance Walked" determined?

Tags: ingress

A badge for "Distance Walked" was recently released. But, I saw this value increase by 2km after driving through city streets at 20-30mph (running Ingress, screen on, occasionally hacking, etc. at stops).
So, does *any* travel under the Ingress speed limit qualify for "Distance Walked", or are there additional restrictions?

Comment: At the stops (e.g. streetlight, stop sign), surely the vehicle was driving slowly enough that its speed mimicked walking. That can add up to a km or two surprisingly quickly.

Comment: This seems like a nice description of how Trekker distance is determined: https://plus.google.com/+RobinDaemen/posts/hBM2DtzKtc9

Comment: @jrennie A very helpful article.  I want to quote the most helpful piece here:

"Ingress tracks your location at certain actions: Hacking, Deploying, Linking, Modding, Firing XMP, Recharging, Dropping/Picking up, Checking missions, NOT capsule loading/unloading, and NOT recycling"

Answer (score 8):

People were monitoring the progress of this stat since it was [introduced](https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts/bTqwtFFexGB) in October 2013 but its mechanics are still being [discussed in communities](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/2c5t4g/running_not_counting_toward_distance_walked/). The best tip I could find about its inner workings is [this one](http://hubllama.hubpages.com/hub/New-Ingress-Badges) :

> There is some sort of speed / play limitation about what counts as "walking" so distance traveled while driving or biking doesn't seem to count. Additionally, some people report not having distance counted while running either. It may also require that there is some "activity" every so often to count toward distance walked. For now, the best bet on this badge seems to be to let it take care of itself while you work toward other goals like destroying enemy portals, linking and fielding, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I found an article [here](https://plus.google.com/+RobinDaemen/posts/hBM2DtzKtc9) describing all the actions you can do in order to be logged by Ingress. Here they are :

- hacking
- deploying
- linking
- modding
- firing XMP
- recharging
- dropping / picking up
- checking missions
- NOT capsule loading / unloading
- NOT recycling

The author of the post also explains how distance is calculated based on these actions, and even show a picture to illustrate his explanations.

The speed limit is real, and is "claimed to be roughly 6 km/hour".

The [Ingress Wikia Trekker article](http://ingress.wikia.com/wiki/Trekker) confirms the rough speed limit: about 7 km/hour. Another Wikia article, about [Metrics in Ingress](http://ingress.wikia.com/wiki/Metrics) claims that the trekker speed limit is "less than 8 km/hour", and the speed lock "checks that an agent is going slower than 60 km/hour".

Beware though, the vast majority of what you can find around the Internets is only based on "user experience", since Niantic Labs never commented on how the trekker is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your scanner up in the foreground and **don't lock your screen between portals**. Doesn't really matter what you do, just keep it up.

Then there is a certain **speed limitation**: Bike/footbike/running/public transport won't count.

However, what will generate you free kilometers is leaving Ingress running on a weak wifi over night, though I am not sure how beneficial that is for your device.

To prevent your device from locking set *Navigate* to a distant portal.

Comment: My understanding at this point is that you need to make location-tracking actions before traveling very far and that speeds below 30 mph or so are fine.